# Magento: Displaying product image in order email

Tags: image, magento, caching, product

To show product image in order email, I have written the following code in template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

```
<?php 
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())
                ->load($_item->getProductId());
?> 
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')
                         ->init($_product, 'image')
                         ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                         ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                         ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                         ->resize(50,50); ?>" 
alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

It works fine. It displays resized product image in order email.

However, I have one problem.

> The product image is fetched from **media/catalog/product/cache**
>   directory. And, if we **Flush Images Cache** from Magento Admin (**System >
>   Cache Management**) then the product image which was displayed before is
>   not displayed in order email. It’s because flushing image cache will
>   clear all cache images from **media/catalog/product/cache** directory.

What would be an appropriate solution to this problem? Is it a good idea to show product image in order email at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
                 ->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>" 
 alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

You can use getSmallImage(), getThumbnail() for different images of the product.